# Error 404 change permalink term custom term taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I'm trying to change the permalink structure of the terms for a custom taxonomy, but it's returning page 404. I want the URL to be: example.com/products/category/category-name.

I tried to use the term_link filter, I even tried to put a slug different from the custom post type, however, without success. I have also updated wp_options on permanent links

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_sps_products_post_type' );
function register_sps_products_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'sps-product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Products',
                'menu_name' => 'Product Manager',
                'singular_name' => 'Product',
                'all_items' => 'All Products'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'post-formats', 'revisions' ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive' => 'products',
            'taxonomies' => array('product-category'),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products' )
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'product-category', array( 'sps-product' ),
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Product Categories',
                'menu_name' => 'Product Categories',
                'singular_name' => 'Product Category',
                'all_items' => 'All Categories'
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%sps-product%/category', 'with_front' => false ),
        )
    );
}

add_filter('term_link', 'idinheiro_permalink_archive_cpt', 10, 2);
function idinheiro_permalink_archive_cpt( $url ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $url, '%sps-product%') ) {
        $url = str_replace( '%sps-product%', 'products', $url );
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the category permalink be in the form of: `example.com/products/category/<category slug>`, then you don't need to hook on `term_link`.

Instead, you could just set the taxonomy's **rewrite slug** to `products/category` *and* you would also register the taxonomy first then followed by the post type. That way, WordPress would see the request (at the above permalink/URL) as a (single) term request and not a post type request.

So for example:

```php
function register_sps_products_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'sps-product', array(
        'labels'  => array( /* your code */ ),
        'public'  => true,
        // ... your other args.
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products' ),
    ) );
}

function register_sps_product_category_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( 'product-category', array( 'sps-product' ), array(
        'labels'  => array( /* your code */ ),
        'public'  => true,
        // ... your other args.
        'rewrite' => array(
            // Use products/category as the rewrite slug.
            'slug'       => 'products/category',
            'with_front' => false,
        ),
    ) );
}

// Register the taxonomy first.
add_action( 'init', 'register_sps_product_category_taxonomy' );

// Then register the post type.
add_action( 'init', 'register_sps_products_post_type' );

// No need to hook on term_link, thus I commented out this part:
//add_filter('term_link', 'idinheiro_permalink_archive_cpt', 10, 2);
```

And remember to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings (admin) page.